# Proof of the uncountability of reals using the diagonal argument—problem?

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

Consider a common proof of the uncountability of $(0,1]$, as presented [here](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Real_Numbers_are_Uncountable/Cantor%27s_Diagonal_Argument) for example:

We assume that the reals can be arranged in a sequence $x_k$, represent every number in $x_k$ by its *nonterminating* decimal expansion, use the diagonal argument to create a sequence of decimal digits that differs from the nonterminating decimal expansion of each number in $x_k$ and then claim that this sequence of digits so generated must be the decimal expansion of some number not in $x_k$.

My problem is with this last step. Could it not be the case that the new sequence of digits is just the *terminating* decimal expansion of some number already in $x_k$?

Would it not be more correct to use the sequence $x_k$ to generate a sequence of all (both terminating and non-terminating) decimal expansion of all numbers in $[0,1)$ and then apply the diagonal argument?

Comment: Who said $\;x_n\;$ is represented by "its non-terminating decimal expansion"?

Comment: Usually, we pick the new series of digits so that the $i$th digit is one of $1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8$ so we can ensure that it does not terminate. Easy enough to do.

Comment: The problem is that non-terminating and terminating overlap. $0.49999999\dots=0.5$. The point of the non-terminating is to pick one representation, and we pick $0.499999\dots$ rather than $0.5$ in the listing.

Comment: The easiest way to avoid this is to take $f_n=\begin{cases}0 & d_{nn}=6 \\ 6 & d_{nn}\neq6\end{cases}$.

Comment: @AsafKaragila $0$ being the digit that can cause problems, maybe we should use, say, $5$ in the first branch?

Comment: Sure, whatever works. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually, we pick the new series of digits so that the ith digit is one of $1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8$ so we can ensure that it does not terminate. Easy enough to do.

The problem is that non-terminating and terminating overlap. $0.49999999⋯=0.5$. Every terminating representation, other than $0$, has a non-terminating representation. The point of the non-terminating clause is to pick one representation, and we pick $0.499999…$ rather than $0.5$ in the listing.